# How to get distinct rowcount using ActiveJdbc?

Tags: activejdbc

How do we get distinct rowcount in activejdbc?  I tried many different variations but none of them worked

```
Tablename.count("?", "distinct id")
Tablename.count("distinct ?", "id") //missing expression
Base.exec("select count(distinct id) from tablename") //return 1 always (probably the count)
```

Comment: what you are trying to do is not any different from plain SQL. What will you get if you just execute: 

    select count(distinct id) from tablename

in the database shell?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong API. Since you are selecting, you need to use any one of the `Base.find...` methods, not `Base.exec`, which is for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.